# getting jquery tag plugin to work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, input

so I've been trying to implement this: http://www.fatihkadirakin.com/dev/jquerytag/

it's a really good tag plugin which allows you to type in facebook-like tags into input field....

unfortunately though it works in firefox and chrome, it doesn't seem to work in IE as the demo demonstrates...

has anyone ever got it to work in IE and if so what changes to the js file did you make

Comment: Could you be more specific? I just tried it in IE9 and it works?

Comment: the one i'm using is IE8...there's still a lot of users using it....basically, the input wont even appear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older IE versions don't have the `indexOf` method on `Array`, so the plugin adds this method to the Array prototype.

Later in the code, the author loops through an array using `for (index in tags)` without any `hasOwnProperty` check. Since `indexOf` is not a builtin property in this case, `"indexOf"` is one of the values that `index` takes on. Since a string is expected, not a function, this fails badly.

Change the loop (starting at line 146) to

```
            var index;
            for (index = 0; index < tags.length; index++) {
                var item = create_tag(tags[index]);
                list.append(item);
            }
```

and it works as expected.

Comment: did you mean line 129? ...i tried it, but the bubbles are still not showing up

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot: I'm looking at the file that's included in the example page -- http://www.fatihkadirakin.com/dev/jquerytag/jquery.tag.js -- which seems to be different from the one you get via the download link.